# Use AFNetworking to download a file from Django server

Tags: ios, django, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking to send a HTTP request to a Django server to download a file to iPhone. However, neither do the console print out "Success" or "Error". I also cannot find the file in the specific dir ".../database". For the server side, the log file is correct ([22/Jan/2015 16:45:49] "GET /main/receivefile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16811) and I can see the request and there is no error. This is my client side code:

```
var parameters = ["username":"u987103"];

let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let outPath = String(format: "%@/database/tmp.txt", documentsPath)


self.man = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

self.op = self.man.GET(url, parameters: parameters,
        success: {(operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject:AnyObject!) in
            println("Success")
        }
        , failure:{(operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error:NSError!) in
            println("Error: %@",error);
        })
op.outputStream = NSOutputStream(toFileAtPath: outPath, append: false)
```

The code corresponding to the request URL in the Django server is:

```
def retrieve_file(request):
    filename = os.path.basename(m_path)
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,m_path)
    wrapper = FileWrapper(file(path))
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper,content_type="text/plain")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="'+filename+'"'
    return response
```

I have tested to download the file using Chrome and as soon as I enter the URL and hit "enter", the file is downloaded to my download folder. So could anyone tell me why it does not work for AFNetwokring?

Comment: have a look at Alamofire, its a work in progress to convert AFNetworking to a more native Swift library (i think its a bit cleaner)

Comment: Thanks and I will check that. So do you think the problem is caused by the language?

Comment: Did you check whether `self.man.GET` returns? Did you try putting breakpoints inside `success` and `failure`?

Comment: I put breakpoints inside `success` and `failure` but nothing happens. How do you check whether `self.man.GET` returns? @tng

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `op.outputStream = ...` - see if that gets hit

Comment: I have set a breakpoint on this line and `op` is `nil`. Does that mean `self.man.GET` did not return a value?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct.

Take a look at the doc here - http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html#//api/name/responseSerializer. You need to specify a response serializer for `AFHttpRequestOperationManager`.

It seems like you are downloading a plain text file, so you can use the default serializer. Add this call:

`self.man.responseSerializer = AFHttpResponseSerializer()`

before you call `self.man.GET`.

The https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide has some details on how the response and request serializers work.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I have one last question. Do you know how to get `filename` from the http response? I tried printing `responseObject` and it is nil.

Comment: Currently it always gets the name `tmp.txt` as hard-coded.

Comment: I have figured it out how to do it. I think I should use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` to do the task rather than this method. The solution is posted below.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is the correct way to do it for AFNetwokring 2.5.0

Reference: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.0/

```
        var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        var man = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configuration)

        var URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL:URL!)

        var downloadTask = man.downloadTaskWithRequest(request, progress: nil,
        destination:{(targetPath:NSURL!,response:NSURLResponse!) -> NSURL! in
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let outPath = String(format: "%@/download/", documentsPath)
        var url:NSURL! = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outPath)
        return url.URLByAppendingPathComponent(response.suggestedFilename as String!)
        },
        completionHandler:{(response:NSURLResponse!,filePath:NSURL!,error:NSError!)  in
            println(response.suggestedFilename)
        })

        downloadTask.resume();
```